# Dash - Setting nav bar for the dashboard Application

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-dash

I am building a Dashboard using Python Dash. I am using **Materialize.css** Framework for css.  I want to create a **Navigation Bar** which the Unordered List must be shown on any devices either Mobile, Desktop. I am referring to this website [Extended Nav Bar with Tabs](https://materializecss.com/navbar.html#). How do I get the webpage more responsive?

The sample code is posted here

```
 layout = html.Div(id='main-page-content',children=[

    #nav wrapper starts here
    html.Div(
        children=[
            #nav bar
            html.Nav(
                #inside div
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.A(
                            'Dashboard Analytics',
                            className='brand-logo',
                            href='/'
                        ),
                        #ul list components
                        html.Ul(
                            children=[
                               html.Li(html.A('Configuration', href='/apps/config')),
                               html.Li(html.A('Segmentation', href='/apps/segmentation')),
                               html.Li(html.A('Main Page', href='/apps/users')), 
                            ],
                            id='nav-mobile',
                            className='right hide-on-med-and-down'
                        ), 
                    ],
                    className='nav-wrapper'
                ),style={'background-color':'#008EFE'}),

        ],
        className='navbar-fixed'
    ),
])

#define the external urls
external_css = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css']

for css in external_css:
    app.css.append_css({'external_url': css})

external_js = ['https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js']

for js in external_js:
  app.scripts.append_script({'external_url': js})
```

when I view the webpage in mobile the options must be shown in Side Navigation. So I can navigate through different pages without actually going back in mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you gave, the example    contains the following element, which is missing from your layout:

```
<a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
```

This is the button that opens the menu on mobile devices. Specifically, the `data-target` property is essential, as it triggers the on-click event.

Unfortunately, there is currently no easy way in Dash to add this attribute to an HTML element (see [this thread](https://community.plot.ly/t/can-data-attributes-be-created-in-dash/7222/7)).

In addition, you forgot to give the `nav` element the class name `'nav-extended'`, but I don't know how essential that is.